# Whats the best way to design DELETE for a restful resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

Trying to find out what is a good way to design a delete.

trying to explain using example:

I have a resource for Employee. The employee has the following fields

```
Employee{
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String emailId
    String managerEmployeeId
    String employeeId
}
```

I want the ability to delete the employee using any of the fields 
e.g. firstName , lastName , employeeId , or managerEmployeeId

How should my resource paths look ideally

Option1: 
is  this a good option ? yes ? no ? why ?

```
/employee/id/{employeeId}
/employee/firstName/{firstName}
/employee/lastName/{lastName}
/employee/managerId/{managerId}
```

Option2:

use of query params

```
    /employee?id=100  ( to delete employee with id 100)

    /employee?firstName=Tom&lastName=Winn (to delete an employee named Tom Winn)

   /employee?managerEmployeeId=400 (delete all employees having manager id as 400)
```

Option 1 looks very RPC-ish to me

I like the second option but I find it very error prone since the fields have to be specified.

In the 2nd option 
I don't like the idea of having a param named firstName and then mapping it to a firstName field in a Java class Employee.  Is this a used paradigm in the industry ?

Further this is for a backend application with xml and written in java( use of loose field names looks very un-java to me)

I would like to understand what is being followed in the industry ( specifically for a strongly typed java+xml based rest systems built in jersey , restEasy or Spring )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote would go for (a slight alteration of) option 1.

```
DELETE /employees/{employeeId}
```

There's no need to specify `/id`, I can't imagine there's ever going to be any confusion (unless you have an employee named some bizarre `UUID`...).  This also leads me to *why* I'd say the others were a *bad* idea:

There should only ever be *one* `Employee` with that `id`, so there is no room for ambiguity.  There are likely to be *many* with the same `firstName`, `lastName` (and even combinations may not be unique).

If you put `/id` in the string, it implies (to me at least) that there may be some other way to uniquely refer to that resource (e.g. the `/firstName` or `/lastName` which you suggest); omitting it leaves it clear that's the *only* way you support referencing a specific `Employee`, and that if they want to find the one with a specific `firstName` and `lastName`, it should be retrieved with a `GET /employees?firstName=Tom&lastName=Winn` type request.

Query parameters in a DELETE sound risky to me, and more like something whatever is *calling* your service should be in charge of.  If you want to `DELETE` all `Employee`s with `managerId=400`, it makes more sense to `GET` those resources: `GET /employees?managerId=400`, and then issue a `DELETE` on all the returned `Employee`s.